# 'iostream' file not found Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, io

Whenever I try to use Xcode 11 to build C++ programs and type in the line:

```
#include <iostream>
```

An error saying "'iostream' file not found shows up. The library I am using is libc++ and not libstdc++.

Other people dont seem to encounter this problem so I do not know what is going on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hey, this really works!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is this a C or C++ project? What's the filename? Did you try to compile it in terminal with `g++ FILE.cpp`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik It is a C++ project and the filename is "abc.cpp". Yes, I tried running it in the terminal and it gave me no error. I compiled and executed the code on Xcode itself and it runs just fine, but the error doesn't seem to budge.

Answer (score 5):

We encountered the same problem while using a C++ class with Objective-C wrapper.

While checking the build command we found Xcode was passing objective-c as the language for clang. On changing the Wrapper file extension to '.mm', XCode started passing language as objective-c++ and the error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add header file path:

`Build Settings -> Search paths ->System Header Search Paths`

add:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/`

Comment: Whomever you are good sir this is the absolute fix!!! thank you!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to avoid this error, here's what I did.

1. Open terminal and enter:
   `xcode-select --install`
2. Use:

```
#include "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream"
```

instead of:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the terminal the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

At the end of the installation process, I quit and reopened Xcode, and the issue was gone.

Comment: Tried it on a lark as Xcode "system header search paths" seems broken. No joy through any side effect of installing, "system header search paths" still broken.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem. A [lot](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250695999?page=2) of people did actually. I've tried reinstalling Xcode, but the error persisted. The only thing that helped is to update everything with `brew update`.